# Wildcards in find VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, find, wildcard

I have the code below that finds any word/text between "<<" anychar ">>" but sometimes only "<<>>" text comes.

How can I write the Wildcards stings to catch "<<>>"  also?

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "\<\<*\>\>*"
    .Replacement.Text = "?????"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchKashida = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
End With
Selection.Find.Execute
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
  .Text = "\<\<[!\<]@[\>]{1;2}"
  .Replacement.Text = "?????"
  .Forward = True
  .Wrap = wdFindContinue
  .Format = False
  .MatchWildcards = True
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Not working: In word VBA an error is generated as follows: 

Run time error '5560'
The find what text contains a Pattern Match expression which is not valid.

Comment: Evidently, then, you're using a system with non-English configuration. It would have helped had you said so. See revised code.

Comment: YES! It works Thank you. Any advanced wildcards doc could you please suggest?

Comment: See: https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm